# Algorithm to compute value of PDF of mixture of many gaussians

Tags: precision, probability, numeric, gaussian

Suppose I have a mixture of 2D gaussians defined by means, covariance matrices. The weight of each gaussian in the mixture is identical. Now I want to compute the value of the probability density function. So obviously I would compute the value for each of the gaussians in the mixture and take the mean. But my mixture contais many gaussians (> 10^4) so I am afraid this could be numerically unstable and probably also slow, when I have to compute exponentials in each of the PDFs. What could be a good approach to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have approximated the gaussians with triangular distributions and obtained a satisfactory approximation.